# Setting a default date in Eonasdan Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ for Calendar functionality

Here is the html

```
         <div class="form-group" id="div_mydatecontainer">
             <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                 <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                 </span>
             </div>
         </div>
```

construct

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     format: 'l',
     locale:'en-gb'
});
```

How can I display a default date which is 20 days from current date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use defaultDate and moment.js (which I believe is required for that plugin anyway)

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     format: 'l',
     locale:'en-gb',
     defaultDate: moment().add(20, 'days')
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Its working. And yes I use moment.js infact moment-with-locales.min.js to get locale features